# Easiet way to access a currency exchange rate in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I started my journey with Android and I would like to make a simple feature that would convert one currency to another. I don't know anything about web services really, I saw some tutorials but none for Android Studio for this.

Could someone explain how this could be done? Or give a link to a beginner-friendly tutorial that would hep understand how to perform such an operation?

Comment: You want to build currency exchange rate app or you just want to find api for currency exchange rate?

Comment: Incidentally, Android Studio is just one of several tools you can use to build Android apps. It's *not* the platform itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [API](https://code.google.com/archive/p/currency-converter-api/) provided by google codes.

It fetches and uses bank web-services to fetch the rate dynamically for java-based application.